# Are unmentioned struct fields *always* initialised to zero (i.e. when the struct is on the stack)?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

From experimentation (in Clang and GCC, with -O2 and -O0) is *seems* that in the following code

```
typedef struct foo_s { int i; int j; } foo_t;
int main(void) {
    foo_t foo = {.i = 42};
    ...
```

foo.j is automatically zero.

Is the guaranteed by C99 onwards, or is it a compiler specific implementation detail?

Note: I've even tried writing 0xFFs to invalid memory below the stack, at the address which foo is later given.

Update: There are a couple of comments stating that this is just because the memory below the stack happens to contain zeros.  The following code makes sure this is not the case, and may prove that GCC -O0 is zeroing memory.

The offsets of -7 and -6 are compiler dependent.  They needed to be different in Clang.

```
typedef struct foo_s { int i; int j; } foo_t;

int main(void) {
    int r;
    int *badstack0 = &r - 7;
    int *badstack1 = &r - 6;

    *badstack0 = 0xFF; // write to invalid ram, below stack
    printf("badstack0 %p, val: %2X\n", badstack0, *badstack0);
    *badstack1 = 0xEE; // write to invalid ram, below stack
    printf("badstack1 %p, val: %2X\n", badstack1, *badstack1);

    // struct test
    foo_t foo = {.i = 42};
    printf("&foo.i %p\n", &foo.i);
    printf("&foo.j %p\n", &foo.j);
    printf("struct test: i:%i j:%i\n", foo.i, foo.j);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
badstack0 0x7fff221e2e80, val: FF
badstack1 0x7fff221e2e84, val: EE
&foo.i 0x7fff221e2e80
&foo.j 0x7fff221e2e84
struct test: i:42 j:0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you provide any initialisers, the members not explicitly mentioned are initialised as if they were static. That's guaranteed by the standard in 6.7.9 (19):

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject; **all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

(Emphasis added by me)

If you don't initialise any member, the values of all members are indeterminate.

Comment: It would be worth adding that in the particular situation, the OP is just having a zeroed stack region in the beginning of the program and that manifests with the `j` member having the value `0`.

Comment: No, even if the stack region is not zeroed, the OP has `foo_t foo = {.i = 42};` an explicit initialisation of one member. Thus the other member must be initialised to 0, as if it were a `static int j;`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Does IBM say the opposite?  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fstrin.htm  "temp_address.postal_code Depends on the storage class of the temp_address variable; if it is static, the value would be NULL."

Comment: They do say that it depends on the storage class, but that contradicts the standard (by the way, the section is 6.7.8 in C99). Since the `struct` is initialised, the members with no explicit initialiser **shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**. In the case of the example on the IBM site, it's a pointer, so it must be initialised to a null pointer.

Answer (score 4):

C guarantees that as long as at least one member of an array/struct/union* is initialized explictily, then all other members will be initialized as if they had static storage duration, as cited in Daniel Fischer's answer. In other words, all the other members are set to zero or NULL automatically.

The storage type of the array/struct/union matters not, they are initialized according to the same rule no matter if they have automatic or static storage duration.

This is not something unique to C99 or later, C has *always* had this requirement. All conforming C compilers follow this rule, it is *normative* and *not* implementation-defined.

This has nothing to do with "debug release" zero outs.

As a matter of fact, this rule is the explanation why you can zero a whole array by writing

`int array[100] = {0}`.

This code means, "initialize the first element to zero, and initialize the 99 remaining ones as if they had static storage duration, ie make them zero too".

---

(*) Those three types are formally named "aggregate type" in the C standard.

Comment: Daniel Fischer's answer should be accepted as the correct one. My answer only adds additional details after edit by the OP.

Comment: If the first member of a union is not the largest, what does the standard specify about the initialization of other members?  For example, if a null pointer, floating-point zero, and integer zero all have different 32-bit representations, what would be the effect of declaring `union {void *moe[1]; float larry[2]; unsigned char curly[12];} STOOGE = {0};`  Clearly the first four bytes of `curly` should hold the `unsigned char` representation of a null pointer, but what about the rest?

Comment: @supercat The standard makes no difference between union and other "aggregate" types, see C11 6.7.9/21. And the rules of initialization applies recursively to all members. In your example, the first item of the first array member would be initialized explicitly to a null pointer, then the rest of all items as if they had static storage duration. That is, the rest of the items of the first array, then all the other array members as well. Everything will be set to zero.

Comment: What sort of zero?  Would the array of pointers be initialized to null pointers, and everything else initialized to all-bits-zero, or what?

Comment: @supercat They will be initialized as if they had static storage duration. Read [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9/10.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I infer that "...and any padding is initialized to zero bits" means "...any internal padding, as well as any portion of the union which extends past the end of the first member..."?

Comment: @supercat Padding means: padding bytes inserted by the compiler to ensure correct alignment. So in practice: the whole union and everything inside it, including padding and other members, will be set to value 0.

Comment: What is the meaning of "value zero" past the end of the first item in the union?  The "value zero" for the first of the remaining items in the union that extends past the first one?