# ansi c structure initialization from c99

Tags: c, migration, structure

I'm converting a code from a C version that allows inline variable declaration and using math in struct type variable initializations to a version that disallows both of them and I need them to work the same. The code I think I need to clarify is this:

```
// definitions

typedef struct poly poly_t;

struct poly
{
    size_t d;    /* degree */
    byte c[512]; /* coefficients */
};

// usage in the middle of the method 
// (contains non-declaring code before)

poly_t tmp = { 1, {1, gf_exp[i]} };
```

and I'm converting this as:

```
poly_t tmp; // at the beginning of function scope

// then at the same spot of previous declaration

tmp.d = 1;
tmp.c[0] = 1;
tmp.c[1] = gf_exp[i];
```

Is this the right way to initialize this structure?

I need both of them initialize the same values in the variable.

Comment: "using math in struct type variable initializations" - this is allowed in every version of the C standard. But you use a variable as initialiser, which is not allowed in any version.

Comment: If the former resulted in a compiler error, that might be related to something else. For example, is the variable declared at file scope or not?

Comment: Beside of fact previous code is valid, Your rewrite does not work as previous code. poly_t tmp = { 1, {1, gf_exp[i]} }; also initializes remaining members of c to zero.

Comment: Does `poly_t tmp = { 1, {1} }; tmp.c[1] = gf_exp[i];` work?

Comment: @Olaf "not allowed in any version". Isn't that only true for static and thread storage duration variables? Automatic variables can use variable expressions in the initialiser. It's not clear from the OP's code where `tmp` is declared. If it is global for example then yes, I agree with what you said.

Comment: It doesn't give any compiler errors, I need to be sure if both works as the same. It works but the output is variable even in the same compiler version, so I can't check for the equality of the result.

Comment: `tmp` was declared in the middle of the method, I needed to declare that at top.

Comment: @TahaPaksu At the top of what? Top of the function or top of the file? If it is an automatic variable inside a function then the two versions of code are not equivalent. The first version will implicitly zero out all non-explicitly set members of the struct (ie, the rest of the array). The second version needs to explicitly do that zeroing.

Comment: function. it's a local variable.

Comment: @kaylum: Not in a `struct` initialiser (not sure if it is allowed if you use braces for simple type initializsers, too, like `int i = {k};`). But e.g. gcc allows that as an extension, but it is not standard.

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I'm a bit unsure now. May need to post a new question on this. Because c11 6.7.9 reads: "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals." and "The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is
unspecified". Those are the main points which I based my understanding on.

Comment: @kaylum: Hmm, you made me think (thanks for that!). Until now, I have uderstood the text for the gcc extension as I stated above and never checked in the standard itself. I re-read it now and checked the standard; I might have missunderstood the gcc doc last time I read it some years ago (not my native language and permanently learning). As I use gcc with extensions for most projects, I did not think about it. I now doubt I'm correct and variable initialisers for any `auto` variable in fact **are** allowed. I withdraw this objection until further proof.

Comment: @kaylum: Sidenote: The standard has a lot of examples, but not a single with a variable, too bad.

Comment: @olaf yes i did notice that too regarding the examples.Adding to my uncertainty. I'll do some more research later. if i can't be sure I'll post a new question.

Comment: @kaylum: I'd really appreciate if you leave me a comment here if you post a question, so I won't miss it. That really bothers me now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not identical. Variables from `tmp.c[2]` to `tmp.c[511]` are uninitialized, and contain garbage.

You can force zero-initalization with `= {0}`:

```
poly_t tmp = {0}; // Set all elements to zero
tmp.d = 1;
tmp.c[0] = 1;
tmp.c[1] = gf_exp[i];
```

Alternatively you can set first elements with intializer:

```
poly_t tmp = {1}; // Set tmp.d to 1, and other elements to zero
tmp.c[0] = 1;
tmp.c[1] = gf_exp[i];
```

Comment: Does `{0}` really set all the elements to zero? Or just the first byte?

Comment: Yes it sets all to zero. If initializer has less elements than target type, then all remaining elements are set to zero.

Comment: Is this feature a standart in all C versions? Sorry, really I'm asking that because I knew that just sets the first byte to `0`

Comment: @TahaPaksu At least [since C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7)

Comment: @TahaPaksu: How about reading the standar**d** yourself, apparently you have more questions and this is not a turotial or consulting site. Note: there is only **one** C standard which is ISO9899:2011 (aka C11). Older versions are not standard. The standards or at least the final (and techically identical) drafts are freely available.

Comment: @Olaf I'm reading it now. While I find the related section of the document, I wanted to ask it here if somebody knows. If I was sure of the version that I'm converting from, I'd first read that, you can be sure. But in this case, it makes 5-6 standards to read.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: The standard has a "changes" section in the foreword already. And google/duckduckgo can also be helpful.

Comment: @Olaf thank you. I think the first zero initialization solved my problem.

Comment: @TahaPaksu You can always start by checking SO first. Most C related questions have already been asked before. For example [Are unmentioned struct fields always initialised to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138238/are-unmentioned-struct-fields-always-initialised-to-zero-i-e-when-the-struct).